# What is wrong with this setter method? (Java)

Tags: java

updateCreditLimit is used to update class attribute creditLimit for a CanteenAccount object. I'm trying to call a setter from a menu class (CanteenMenu) that will update CanteenAccount "ca1" creditLimit with this code:

```
case 6: 
    System.out.println("Enter new Credit Limit: ");
    double newLimit = input.nextDouble();
    ca1.updateCreditLimit(newLimit);
    break;
```

The setter is in a different class (CanteenAccount) and is a static method:

```
public static void updateCreditLimit(double newLimit) {
    creditLimit = newLimit;
}
```

`creditLimit` is a static variable.
Why won't this work? I don't understand what am I doing wrong!

Comment: Why is it static? That would result in all your accounts having the same limit.

Comment: If the variable is static then you're not updating anything in `ca1` - you are updating a variable that belongs to the *class*, not your specific account. But you didn't say what was not working, so it's hard to tell you how to do it right. Please [edit] your question and include the class definition, what you wanted to do and what happened instead.

Comment: RealSkeptic and Kayaman thanks for the comments, It is part of my assignment, the assignment requires that creditLimit be a static variable. updateCreditLimit is used to update creditLimit variable via user input from the menu class

Comment: You access static members by qualifying by the class name, not the object name. Although the latter is valid Java, it's discouraged as anyone reading your code (including yourself in about a month's time) cannot see it's static. ('qualifying' means what's before the `.`, in this case `ca1.` which should `CanteenAccount.`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try  this :

```
case 6: 
                System.out.println("Enter new Credit Limit: ");
                double newLimit = input.nextDouble();
                CanteenAccount.updateCreditLimit(newLimit);
                break;
```

Static methods can be called directly...

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the static method on class level and not on the instance:

```
CanteenAccount.updateCreditLimit(newLimit)
```

Comment: May I ask why I get -1 for this. The OP asked why his code is not working for which i provided a correct answer. Questioning the usage of static or the code itself is another topic.